# chiral partition function - group integral

Tags: partition-function, chirality, effective-field-theory, 1pi-effective-action

I am reading this [Thermodynamics of chiral symmetry](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269387916522) and i really want to know how to perform a group integral, and why it is proportional to the effective action in this case? I have not been able to find suitable literature that goes into detail of how this works. A lot of the steps are implied in the linked article, so if i could get a hint as how to proced that would be appreciated very much!

My question is a bit open, so maybe to make it a bit more specific, i am right now trying to calculate this simpler version of the partition function:

$Z = \int_{U(1)} dU_0 \exp\big(\Sigma VM \mathsf{Tr}(U_0 + U^{\dagger}_0) \big)$

where $\Sigma$ is the chiral condensate, V the volume $\frac{L^3}{T}=L^3\beta$. Here i should use that $U \approx e^{i\phi}$

I know that i should expect getting a Bessel function of the form they get in eq. 27 in the article:

$$Z_2(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} = \frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n}n!(n+1)!}$$

I am not sure how the integral handles the group U(1). From what i have found this is a type of Haar integral, but i can not seem to find any information as how to going on solving it. Any hints will be appreciated.

In general if anyone has more information of the subject, that is easier to understand than provided in the article, that would be fantastic.

**EDIT:** To clarify further i have to points (that are actually mentioned in the article, but i thought i might as well sum it up here:
1. $\Sigma VM$ is a dimensionless combination of the quark mass.
2. U is defined as $U(x) = U_0 e^{i \xi(x)}$ and $U^{\dagger}(x) = e^{-i \xi(x)}U_0^{\dagger}$ where $U_0=u^2$ and $u_n(x) = exp\{2\pi i \frac{n_1x_1+n_2x_2+n_3x_3}{L} +n_4x_4T\}$